# Convert time series data from different timeframes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, time-series

Is there a Library in JS to convert time series data timeframes?
I have data generated every minute that I will get from an IOT device. And in the app I am developing there will be a chart where we will be able to visualize data switching between different timeframes (1m, 30m, 1h, 1d and so on), just like classical stock market charts.

It's a pretty simple task to add all the 1m data and make an average. But to generate one new data information for every 30m, for example, is not so obvious. As there are plenty of sotck, forex and crypto websites out there, I imagine someone must have shared a good library.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to my question on my own.
I did make use of a library called moment js, which makes it easy to group array objects by hour, week, month, quarter and so on. Afterward, it is just a matter of counting the grouped objects length and making an average out of it.
Here is my final code:

```
meanByTimeframe = function(timeframe, data) {
    const momentData = _.map(data, item => {
        return {
            date: moment(item[date])
                .startOf(timeframe)
                .format(),
            values: parseInt(item[value])
        }
    });
    const groupedData = _.groupBy(momentData, "date")
    return _.mapValues(groupedData, item => {
        return _.meanBy(item, 'values')
    })
}
```

Voilà!